# Angular 5 - HttpClient XML Post - Http failure during parsing

Tags: javascript, xml, angular, typescript

I am trying to login on a local webservice using xml:

Here is the code:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'text/xml',
    'Accept':  'text/xml',
    'Response-Type': 'text'
  })
};


login() {
    const postedData = `
        <authenticationDetail>
            <userName>myusername</userName>
            <password>mypassword</password>
        </authenticationDetail>`;
    return this.http.post('http://localhost/login.ws', postedData, httpOptions)
    .subscribe(
        result => {
            console.log('This result is' + result);
        },
        error => {
            console.log('There was an error: ', error);
        }
    );
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Http failure during parsing for 'http://localhost/login.ws'
```

What is the problem here? How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this error reported when you make the request to the server or is the the  response value of the subscribe.

Comment: It's displayed after: 'There was an error: '  ... HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: etc

Comment: Added the code change as an answer because comments are really poor formatted. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and change your request to this:

```
login(){ 
const headers = new HttpHeaders(); 
headers = headers.append('Content-Type': 'text/xml'); 
headers = headers.append('Accept', 'text/xml'); 
let body = '<authenticationDetail>' 
           '<username>Username</username>' 
           '<password>Password</password>' 
           '</authenticationDetail>'; 

return this.http.post('localhost/login.ws',body , { headers: headers, responseType: 'text' })
.subscribe(
        res => {
        parseString(res.text(), (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                return console.log('invalid XML');
            }

            console.log(result);
        })
    },error => {
            console.log('There was an error: ', error);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I think it is a parse problem, as it is hard to diagnose, but check the code above I edited it to add a parse on the response, try both: parseString(res.text(), or parseString(res,  as I do not remember if by asking for a text response will need a .text() on the response.

Answer (score 1):

Have your tried

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'text/xml',
        'Accept':  'text/xml',
        'Response-Type': 'text'
    }), 
    responseType: 'text'
};
```

The responseType has to be set to `text` not only in the headers but also in `httpOptions`. Otherwise Angular will parse the response of the call as JSON.

Comment: What das login.ws return? Did you check the network tab? Is it an empty response or is there some binary data in the response?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const postedData = '<authenticationDetail>' +
                   '<userName>myusername</userName>' +
                   '<password>mypassword</password>' +
                   '</authenticationDetail>';
```

Template string adds whitespace char "new line", try the classic approach with regular strings.

Comment: No, that made no difference in this case